# Copy Numbers from end of string

Tags: c#, excel

Here's something I can't get my head around and I would appreciate some help :)

At the moment I have fields on an Excel spreadsheet that have customer's addresses and phone numbers. However the phone numbers are at the end of each string in the address field e.g

> Name,Address,Landline,Mobile
>
> Johnson,2 Oxton Road Moreton CH45 9JB 07854213658 721 2569,

I need it to go to

> Johnson,2 Oxton Road Moreton CH45 9JB,07854213658,721 2569

Any ideas? The phone numbers are always at the end of the string

I can also write in c# but I can't figure out where to start

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: In general there is no way, because you are even using spaces INSIDE the telephone number (`721 2569`)... So you could have `721 2569 555 12345` and it would be TWO telephone numbers

Comment: So basically you want to put some comma in your data? Does the phone number always contains a blank?

Comment: Is this someone's real data? If so you should edit this question to be more generic.

Comment: AND the second part of the zip code could be a number (`9JB` could be `123` if I remember how USA zip codes are made)

Comment: The phone numbers can range but there will always be a space between the 2 phone numbers. but the landline e.g 721 2569 may be all in one or have the area code. And this isn't someone's data, it's completely random

Comment: It's only because I have 4000 fields of this and it would take forever to go through :)

Comment: Just asking to get a logic how to insert the commas because without you can't do a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you always have Address(space)Landline(space)mobile

and mobile always is ###(space)####.

Here's a way to do it with Excel.

```
A1: Johnson,2 Oxton Road Moreton CH45 9JB 07854213658 721 2569,
```

You can get the number of spaces in the string: `B1: =len(A1)-len(substitute(A1," ",""))`

Here after, you can replace the correct spaces with commas, using substitute again:

```
C1: =substitute(A1," ",",",B1-2)
D1: =substitute(C1," ",",",B1-2)
```

We're doing B1-2 in both, as the second space we want to replace has changed from the 7th to the 6th space.

You still need to remove the last comma, this could be done with: `E1: =left(D1,len(D1)-1)`

This can ofcourse all be nested:

```
B1: =left(substitute(substitute(A1," ",",",len(A1)-len(substitute(A1," ",""))-2)," ",",",len(A1)-len(substitute(A1," ",""))-2),len(A1)-1)
```

Notice I'm just using the length of the old string, as the length shouldn't change when replacing two spaces with two commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex here. It is hard to parse but it can be very useful for one time  parsing text data:

```
var userInfo = "Johnson,2 Oxton Road Moreton CH45 9JB 07854213658 721 2569,";
var regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<address>.+) (?<landline>\\d{11}) (?<mobile>(\\d{3} \\d{4})|(\\d{7})),$");
regEx.Replace(userInfo, "${address},${landline},${mobile}")
```

The result would be:

> "Johnson,2 Oxton Road Moreton CH45 9JB,07854213658,721 2569"

You might need to tweak regex for your data. But it must be much faster than manual editing.

You can find your functions [regexlib](http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).